# using serial port and OSX screen to do terminal GUI

Tags: macos, embedded, gnu-screen, ansi-escape

I'd like to upgrade the output from my embedded C projects that sends debug information over the serial port using extended characters, like frame edges and corners (like from [here](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/table5-13.html) ).  I'm on OSX and using screen.  I have found [a library](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37439.0) that implements the basic ANSI escape codes like change foreground/background color, bold, italic, etc.

Question is - does screen on OSX support some way of interpreting extended ASCII/ANSI codes so that I can get access to these fancy character sets (Maybe even emoji?  :-)?

I have been playing around with adding more escape sequences to access extended character set, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced [Ansiterm](http://code.google.com/p/qrptracker/source/browse/trunk/Arduino/libraries/Ansiterm/Ansiterm.cpp) has no functions which use the VT100 line-drawing characters.  It is a special, hard-coded case.

The question about "screen on OSX" could be taken in two ways:

- GNU screen running in a terminal window (usually Terminal or Iterm2), or
- just the Terminal program.

Any of those support VT100 line-drawing.  They emulate (imitate) [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html), which in turn emulates (and extends) VT100, VT220, VT420.  Those are similar but different.  Most applications use a library such as [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) to use different terminals effectively.

Emoji is a special case of Unicode; some people say Terminal.app does this (using UTF-8):

- [Emoji Terminal Prompt](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/33ex2m/emoji_terminal_prompt/)
- [Customize the Command Line by Adding Emoji Icons to the Bash Prompt](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/08/add-emoji-command-line-bash-prompt/)

Comment: Thanks for this info, I was having a hard time understanding how all of these things fit together and emulate each other.

Comment: To clarify the question, I'm using GNU screen to talk to a serial port connected to an embedded project, and I want to know how fancy I can make the output from my embedded project.  This whole thing started when I realized that i could use escape sequences to control the terminal's cursor position and make "control-panel" style debug output from my sensors instead of the usual scrolling println() statements.

Comment: I have been [reading the vt100 terminal](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html) and see the parts about the different character sets G0, G1, and G2, but I am not sure how the currently used set is specified. 

So for example if I wanted to draw a corner (character 107) I would send ^(1 to load the special character set into G0 and then write 107 to the port?  Or do I need to send another escape sequence to select G0?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Well - it wouldn't be exactly that sequence (in the link, the description *follows* the sequence: you would use `ESC ( 0`).  That loads the character set.  Then you use one of the *shift* sequences (shift in, shift out, single shift, locking shift) to determine which character sets are used.